# Merge nested array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects with a nested array of objects like:

```
var cars = [
  {
    Plate: '112211',
    Details:
      [
        {
          Desc: 'Blah11 Blah Blah',
        Miles: '111',
        Color: 'blue'
        },
        {
          Desc: 'Blah B22lah Blah',
        Miles: '222',
        Color: 'green'
        },
      ],
      Make:'Honda'
  },
      Plate: '223322',
    Details:
      [
        {
          Desc: 'Blah Blah B33lah',
        Miles: '333',
        Color: 'yellow'
        },
        {
          Desc: 'Blah B44lah Blah',
        Miles: '444',
        Color: 'red'
        }
      ],
      Make:'GMC'
  },
      Plate: '334433',
    Details:
      [
        {
          Desc: 'Bl55ah Blah Blah',
        Miles: '555',
        Color: 'blue'
        },
        {
          Desc: 'Blah B66lah Blah',
        Miles: '666',
        Color: 'pink'
        },
      ],
      Make:'Ford'
  }
]
```

I am trying to find a way to turn it into a new array that flattens or merges the nested array. The goal would be to have something like:

```
[
  {
    Plate: '112211',
    Desc: 'Blah11 Blah Blah',
    Miles: '111',
    Color: 'blue',
    Make:'Honda'
  },
  {
    Plate: '112211',
    Desc: 'Blah B22lah Blah',
    Miles: '222',
    Color: 'green',
    Make: 'Honda'
    },
    {
    Plate: '223322',
    Desc: 'Blah Blah B333lah',
    Miles: '333',
    Color: 'yellow'
    Make: 'GMC'
    },
    {
    Plate: '223322',
    Desc: 'Blah Bl444ah B33lah',
    Miles: '444',
    Color: 'red',
    Make: 'GMC'
    },
    {
    Plate: '334433',
    Desc: 'Bl555ah Blah B33lah',
    Miles: '555',
    Color: 'blue',
    Make: 'Ford'
    },
    {
    Plate: '334433',
    Desc: 'Blah Bl666ah B33lah',
    Miles: '666',
    Color: 'pink',
    Make: 'Ford'
    },
]
```

lodash _.flatten and _.flattenDeep didn't do anything. I have also tried doing a _.chain and flatten to build a new array, but that come up empty

```
var actions = _.chain(cars).flatten("Details");

        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            actions.each(function(action) {
                list.push(cars[i].Plate);
                list.push(action);
                list.push(cars[i].Make);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```js
function merge(collection) {
  return _(collection).map(function(obj) {
      return _(obj)
        .pickBy(_.isArray)
        .values()
        .flatten()
        .map(function(dest) {
          return _.merge(dest, _.omitBy(obj, _.isArray));
        })
        .value();
    })
    .flatten()
    .value();
}

var cars = [{
  Plate: '112211',
  Details: [{
    Desc: 'Blah11 Blah Blah',
    Miles: '111',
    Color: 'blue'
  }, {
    Desc: 'Blah B22lah Blah',
    Miles: '222',
    Color: 'green'
  }],
  Make: 'Honda'
}, {
  Plate: '223322',
  Details: [{
    Desc: 'Blah Blah B33lah',
    Miles: '333',
    Color: 'yellow'
  }, {
    Desc: 'Blah B44lah Blah',
    Miles: '444',
    Color: 'red'
  }],
  Make: 'GMC'
}, {
  Plate: '334433',
  Details: [{
    Desc: 'Bl55ah Blah Blah',
    Miles: '555',
    Color: 'blue'
  }, {
    Desc: 'Blah B66lah Blah',
    Miles: '666',
    Color: 'pink'
  }],
  Make: 'Ford'
}];

var result = merge(cars);
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.5.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but this gets the job done:

```js
var cars = [
  {
    Plate: '112211',
    Details:
      [
        {
          Desc: 'Blah11 Blah Blah',
        Miles: '111',
        Color: 'blue'
        },
        {
          Desc: 'Blah B22lah Blah',
        Miles: '222',
        Color: 'green'
        },
      ],
      Make:'Honda'
  },
  {
      Plate: '223322',
    Details:
      [
        {
          Desc: 'Blah Blah B33lah',
        Miles: '333',
        Color: 'yellow'
        },
        {
          Desc: 'Blah B44lah Blah',
        Miles: '444',
        Color: 'red'
        }
      ],
      Make:'GMC'
  },
  {
      Plate: '334433',
    Details:
      [
        {
          Desc: 'Bl55ah Blah Blah',
        Miles: '555',
        Color: 'blue'
        },
        {
          Desc: 'Blah B66lah Blah',
        Miles: '666',
        Color: 'pink'
        },
      ],
      Make:'Ford'
  }
];

var details = [];
_.each(cars, function(car) {
  var keys = _.keys(car);
  _.each(car.Details, function(dtl) {
    _.each(keys, function(key) {
      if (key !== 'Details') {
        dtl[key] = car[key];
      }
    });
    details.push(dtl);
  });
});

console.log(details);
  
document.querySelector('#details').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(details);
document.querySelector('#numDetails').innerHTML = details.length;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="numDetails"></div>
<div id="details"></div>
```

I am sure there's a cleaner way (using `_.filter` or some such) to remove 'Details' from the keys, but it's sleepy where I am ;).

Answer (score 0):

If flattening won't work, you can just reduce. Here I construct each of the cars given using the params in details so they can remain monomorphic while they're being flattened and beyond, if you choose.

Ideally the way you have your state set up shouldn't have to have separate keys under the details one. It's simpler to avoid nesting them or keep them on objects that really use them, if that's the case.

```js
function flattenCarList(prevCars, car) {
  var Details = car.Details;
  delete car.Details;

  var carProto = Object.create(car.prototype || null)
  var keys = Object.keys(Details);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    Details[i] = carProto[i] = keys[i];
  }

  var carSet = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Details.length; i++) {
    carSet.push(new Details[i]);
  }

  return prevCars.concat(carSet);
}

var cars = [{
  Make: 'Edzel',
  Plate: 123456,
  Details: {
    Desc: 'Don\'t ask',
    Miles: 32,
    Colour: 'Sickly Green'
  }
}];

// Now let's really get to the point.
cars.reduce(flattenCarList);

document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += 'RESULTS:<br />' + JSON.stringify(cars);
```

```html
<code id="status"></code>
```